# Facebook android SDK gives error com.facebook.android.katana.ProxyAuth has leaked window

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I want help in this respect
I am calling facebook.authorize method.
But the logcat gives com.facebook.android.katana.ProxyAuth has leaked window error and application force closes.

Comment: Just would like to add that facebook android APIs were found broken a few days back with strange error messages like UFO on earth coming up many times while publishing. http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/de061e48b8ca79d3

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue ? I am facing this even now :(